# What is the recommended Nodejs version for Parse Server 4.2.0?

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I've been using parse-server very stable for a while now on nodejs 10.15.1 on AWS.
What's the best way to check out if I can run it on a more recent version?
What's the max recommended nodejs version for parse-server 4.2.0?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Parse Server `4.2.0` you can see in `package.json`:

```
"node": ">= 8"
```

The package has a *minimum* requirement of Node 8.

Parse Server is currently (as of 26 May 2020) CI'ed on Node `10.14.2` and `12.12.0`, and I have seen Parse Server `4.2.0` running in production on Node `14.x` flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks! Added the version to the question. Is this a general rule of thumb for Node that using a higher (production) version should be safe? Do they usually just add features and fix bugs in higher versions? Not a Node expert, asking out of curiosity.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the package maintainer to ensure that the compatible node versions are specified in `package.json`. Currently it says `node >= 8` which means the maintainer assumes that Parse Server runs on any node version >= 8. You can assume that's true unless reported otherwise. If an issue is encountered on higher node versions, it would usually get reported and fixed. The safe side is to use the node version on which Parse Server is tested before release, but you can always fork Parse Server and run all tests on any node version yourself.